# Service Fabric - how do I expose a wcf service externally

Tags: wcf, azure-service-fabric

I have looked through the docs on wcf on **azure service fabric** but it seems the only examples show how to expose it to other fabric services. I want to expose a wcf endpoint like I would a rest end point, so I can map it to a public IP address.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this exact scenario.

You don't need to return a listener at all.  You need to open an endpoint in the 'Service Manifest.xml'.  You bind the ssl cert here etc (I'll assume that you know this part).

```
<Endpoint Name="Test.WcfTypeEndpoint" Protocol="https" Type="Input" CertificateRef="MySSL" Port="44330"  />
```

You can now open Service Hosts and it will route requests to them. Use a strong wildcard in the binding when opening the service - otherwise it won't resolve on the node that it ends up on.

```
public class InternalBinding : Binding
{
    private readonly HttpsTransportBindingElement _transport;

    public InternalBinding()
    {
         _transport = new HttpTransportBindingElement
         {
             HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard,
             // etc
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Curious why the strong wildcard is needed since it is the default for system provided WCF bindings - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.hostnamecomparisonmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Would have been left in there from when I was trying different ComparisonModes most likely.  From memory, other ComparisonModes didn't work so I may have stated it explicitly to save others time experimenting.